# nginx configuration no trailing slash / and redirect to trailing slash /

Tags: nginx

Nginx Config file looks like the following:

## Inside http block

```
server {
        listen *:80 default_server;
        server_name "";
        # return 444;
        root /var/www/default_server;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.default_server.log debug;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.default_server.log custom_made_access_log_1;
        port_in_redirect on;
        server_name_in_redirect on;
        server_tokens on;
        index index.html index.htm default.html default.htm index.php;
        merge_slashes on;
        location = /basic_status {
                stub_status on;
                allow 192.168.80.1;
                deny all;
        }
        location = / {
        }
        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                location ~* ^/phpmyadmin$ {
                        rewrite ^/(phpmyadmin)$ /$1/ last;
                }
                location ~* ^/(.+\.php)$ {
                        include fastcgi.conf;
                        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
                        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
                        fastcgi_index index.php;
                        include fastcgi_params;
                }
                location ~* ^/(.+\.(png|swf|pdf|jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|htm|xml|txt|zip|rar|fla|mov|mp4))$ {
                }
        }
        location /phpmyadmin/ {
                        alias /var/www/default_server/phpmyadmin/;
                        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.default_server.phpMyAdmin.log debug;
                        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.default_server.phpMyAdmin.log custom_made_access_log_1;
#                       try_files $uri $uri/ /phpmyadmin/index.php?$query_string;
                        location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/setup {

                        }
                        location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
                                include fastcgi.conf;
                                fastcgi_split_path_info ^/phpmyadmin/(.+?\.php)(.*)$;
                                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                                fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
                                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
                                fastcgi_index index.php;
                                include fastcgi_params;
                        }
                        location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.(png|swf|pdf|jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|htm|xml|txt|zip|rar|fla|mov|mp4))$ {
                                #avoid processing of calls to unexisting static files
                                try_files $uri =404;
                        }
        }
}
```

I have 2 cases as following:

Case 1: http://192.168.80.129/phpmyadmin/

case 2: http://192.168.80.129/phpmyadmin

Case 1 works good. the location

```
location /phpmyadmin/
```

works as expected.

the problem relay on Case 2
which is without the trailing slash.

as you can see on the above config:

under the server directive I configured the "root"
as following:

```
root /var/www/default_server;
```

and Also , As you can see on the above config , I configured inside the location /phpmyadmin/

```
location /phpmyadmin/
```

the following:

```
alias /var/www/default_server/phpmyadmin/;
```

Also , inside the block location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+.php)$

```
location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$
```

I configured the following

```
fastcgi_split_path_info ^/phpmyadmin/(.+?\.php)(.*)$;
```

what I can see in the DEBUG log is the following:

once I browse to http://192.168.80.129/phpmyadmin
then I see in the DEBUG LOG the following

```
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [debug] 52078#0: *1 HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

and the part of the full log file:

```
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [debug] 52078#0: *1 test location: "/"
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [debug] 52078#0: *1 test location: "phpmyadmin/"
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [debug] 52078#0: *1 test location: "basic_status"
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [debug] 52078#0: *1 test location: ~ "^/phpmyadmin$"
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [debug] 52078#0: *1 using configuration "^/phpmyadmin$"
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [debug] 52078#0: *1 http cl:-1 max:1048576
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [debug] 52078#0: *1 rewrite phase: 3
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [debug] 52078#0: *1 http script regex: "^/(phpmyadmin)$"
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [notice] 52078#0: *1 "^/(phpmyadmin)$" matches "/phpmyadmin", client: 192.168.80.1, server: , request: "GET /phpmyadmin HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.80.129"
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [debug] 52078#0: *1 http script copy: "/"
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [debug] 52078#0: *1 http script capture: "phpmyadmin"
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [debug] 52078#0: *1 http script copy: "/"
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [debug] 52078#0: *1 http script regex end
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [notice] 52078#0: *1 rewritten data: "/phpmyadmin/", args: "", client: 192.168.80.1, server: , request: "GET /phpmyadmin HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.80.129"
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [debug] 52078#0: *1 post rewrite phase: 4
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [debug] 52078#0: *1 uri changes: 11
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [debug] 52078#0: *1 test location: "/"
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [debug] 52078#0: *1 test location: "phpmyadmin/"
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [debug] 52078#0: *1 test location: ~ "^/phpmyadmin/setup"
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [debug] 52078#0: *1 test location: ~ "^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$"
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [debug] 52078#0: *1 test location: ~ "^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.(png|swf|pdf|jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|htm|xml|txt|zip|rar|fla|mov|mp4))$"
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [debug] 52078#0: *1 using configuration "/phpmyadmin/"
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [debug] 52078#0: *1 rewrite phase: 1
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [debug] 52078#0: *1 test location: "/"
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [debug] 52078#0: *1 test location: "phpmyadmin/"
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [debug] 52078#0: *1 test location: ~ "^/phpmyadmin/setup"
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [debug] 52078#0: *1 test location: ~ "^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$"
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [debug] 52078#0: *1 using configuration "^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$"
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [debug] 52078#0: *1 event timer del: 18: 707626498
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [debug] 52078#0: *1 http process request line
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [debug] 52078#0: *1 http request line: "GET /themes/pmahomme/jquery/jquery-ui.css HTTP/1.1"
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [debug] 52078#0: *1 http uri: "/themes/pmahomme/jquery/jquery-ui.css"
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [debug] 52078#0: *1 http args: ""
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [debug] 52078#0: *1 http exten: "css"
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [debug] 52078#0: *1 posix_memalign: 00005626A1D05AF0:4096 @16
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [debug] 52078#0: *1 http process request header line
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [debug] 52078#0: *1 http header: "Host: 192.168.80.129"
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [debug] 52078#0: *1 http header: "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:83.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/83.0"
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [debug] 52078#0: *1 http header: "Accept: text/css,*/*;q=0.1"
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [debug] 52078#0: *1 http header: "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5"
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [debug] 52078#0: *1 http header: "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate"
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [debug] 52078#0: *1 http header: "Connection: keep-alive"
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [debug] 52078#0: *1 http header done
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [debug] 52078#0: *1 generic phase: 0
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [debug] 52078#0: *1 rewrite phase: 1
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [debug] 52078#0: *1 test location: "/"
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [debug] 52078#0: *1 test location: "phpmyadmin/"
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [debug] 52078#0: *1 test location: ~ "^/phpmyadmin$"
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [debug] 52078#0: *1 test location: ~ "^/(.+\.php)$"
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [debug] 52078#0: *1 test location: ~ "^/(.+\.(png|swf|pdf|jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|htm|xml|txt|zip|rar|fla|mov|mp4))$"
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [debug] 52078#0: *1 using configuration "^/(.+\.(png|swf|pdf|jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|htm|xml|txt|zip|rar|fla|mov|mp4))$"
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [debug] 52078#0: *1 http cl:-1 max:1048576
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [debug] 52078#0: *1 rewrite phase: 3
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [debug] 52078#0: *1 post rewrite phase: 4
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [debug] 52078#0: *1 generic phase: 5
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [debug] 52078#0: *1 generic phase: 6
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [debug] 52078#0: *1 generic phase: 7
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [debug] 52078#0: *1 generic phase: 8
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [debug] 52078#0: *1 access phase: 9
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [debug] 52078#0: *1 access phase: 10
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [debug] 52078#0: *1 access phase: 11
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [debug] 52078#0: *1 post access phase: 12
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [debug] 52078#0: *1 generic phase: 13
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [debug] 52078#0: *1 generic phase: 14
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [debug] 52078#0: *1 content phase: 15
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [debug] 52078#0: *1 content phase: 16
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [debug] 52078#0: *1 content phase: 17
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [debug] 52078#0: *1 content phase: 18
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [debug] 52078#0: *1 content phase: 19
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [debug] 52078#0: *1 content phase: 20
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [debug] 52078#0: *1 http filename: "/var/www/default_server/themes/pmahomme/jquery/jquery-ui.css"
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [debug] 52078#0: *1 add cleanup: 00005626A1DA7AD8
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [error] 52078#0: *1 open() "/var/www/default_server/themes/pmahomme/jquery/jquery-ui.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 192.168.80.1, server: , request: "GET /themes/pmahomme/jquery/jquery-ui.css HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.80.129"
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [debug] 52078#0: *1 http finalize request: 404, "/themes/pmahomme/jquery/jquery-ui.css?" a:1, c:1
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [debug] 52078#0: *1 http special response: 404, "/themes/pmahomme/jquery/jquery-ui.css?"
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [debug] 52078#0: *1 http set discard body
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [debug] 52078#0: *1 xslt filter header
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [debug] 52078#0: *1 HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: nginx/1.18.0
Date: Sat, 12 Dec 2020 13:40:10 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 153
Connection: keep-alive
```

and I can see the source of the problem starts from the following row

```
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [debug] 52078#0: *1 http request line: "GET /themes/pmahomme/jquery/jquery-ui.css HTTP/1.1"
2020/12/12 15:40:10 [debug] 52078#0: *1 http uri: "/themes/pmahomme/jquery/jquery-ui.css"
```

as you can see the problem is:

```
"GET /themes/pmahomme/jquery/jquery-ui.css HTTP/1.1"
```

Why the request become

```
/themes/pmahomme/jquery/jquery-ui.css
```

and not as

```
/phpmyadmin/themes/pmahomme/jquery/jquery-ui.css
```

so , assuming that this is the way I would like to implement.
what I should do in order to overcome of the issue.

When the Location Block

```
location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        location ~* ^/phpmyadmin$ {
                rewrite ^/(phpmyadmin)$ /$1/ last;
        }
}
```

handle the request , then the rewrite works fine , but I found that the filesystem is trying to locate the files using the configuration of

```
root /var/www/default_server;
```

rather than using the alias configuration

```
alias /var/www/default_server/phpmyadmin/;
```

which reside inside the location block of

```
location /phpmyadmin/
```

Comment: The request becomes that way because PHPMyAdmin things it is located in `/` folder. Therefore it generates URLs relative to `/`. PHPMyAdmin thinks this because of the `fastcgi_split_path_info` statement. Easiest way is to use a redirect to the version with `/` in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Last what i did is the following Approach:

```
location ~* ^/phpmyadmin$ {
return 301 http://$host:$server_port/phpmyadmin/;
}
    
location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/$ {
return 301 http://$host:$server_port/phpmyadmin/;
}
```

By this I was able to redirecting the Upper Case and Lower Case to a specific URL

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you just want to use PHPMyAdmin under `/phpmyadmin/`. Why don't you just deliver (instead of delivering content under `/phpmyadmin`) a redirect from `/phpmyadmin` to `/phpmyadmin/` and be done with it?

```
location /phpmyadmin
{
    return 303 https://example.com/phpmyadmin/;
}
```

Untested.